# jQuery ler json e mostrar subníveis somente se existirem

Tags: jquery, json, array

Gostaria de fazer um validação, fazer um for para printar o primeiro nível e segundo nível de um json, o segundo nível deverá ser printado somente se haver esse segundo nível no item do array atual. 
Ex de json a baixo:

```
content = {
  "primeiroNivel0": {
    "title":"Titulo Bonito",
    "id":"001",
    "url":"souUmaUrl",
     "segundoNível":  {                                                                              
         "title":"Titulo subnivel",
          "id":"001.01",
          "url":"souUmaUrlDeSubnivel",
          }
},
"primeiroNivel1": {
    "title":"Titulo Bonito1",
    "id":"002",
    "url":"souUmaUrl2"
  }
}
```

Os primeiros niveis seriam printados num for, e o segundo nível desses seria somente se eles existisse.

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer uma função recursiva que verifica se uma das chaves é um objeto, por exemplo com `if (typeof prop === 'object')`. Uma sugestão seria assim:

```js
var content = {
  "primeiroNivel0": {
    "title": "Titulo Bonito",
    "id": "001",
    "url": "souUmaUrl",
    "segundoNível": {
      "title": "Titulo subnivel",
      "id": "001.01",
      "url": "souUmaUrlDeSubnivel",
    }
  },
  "primeiroNivel1": {
    "title": "Titulo Bonito1",
    "id": "002",
    "url": "souUmaUrl2"
  }
}

function mostrarConteudo(obj, nivel) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(chave) {
    var prop = obj[chave];
    if (typeof prop === 'object') mostrarConteudo(prop, chave);
    else console.log(nivel, '>', chave, prop);
  });
}

mostrarConteudo(content);
```